# Accepting different types of collections as an argument

Tags: c#, collections, parameters

I have a method that takes a collection of type float as an argument. Most of the time a `ReadOnlyCollection<float>` is passed to the method but sometimes different types of collections like a List are also passed.

What would be the best type for the parameter? Should I use: `public void MyMethod(Collection<float>)`? Is it good practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you are doing with the collection.

If you just want to enumerate over it, pass in `IEnumerable<float>`. If you need to also add/remove items, use `ICollection<float>`. If you need to access by index, use `IList<float>`.

From your description of the different types, you do not need to add items, so `IEnumerable<float>` should be fine.

In general, use the most general type you can (interface over implementation, something with less methods than one with more). See the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (the L in the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) design principles).

Comment: +1 To further Oded's point about favouring interfaces, this paves the way for better composition of unit tests in future (through interface mocking / stubbing).